# How can I find variables separated by a unique character?

Tags: regex, perl

I am not very familiar with perl, but I am wondering if this would be possible to do?

So I have a file that looks like:

```
Stringa = Stringx Stringz
Stringb = Stringy
Stringc = Stringw Stringx Stringu
```

Where on the left hand side I have a single word.  On the right hand side I have multiple words.  I want to create a hash table, where the key is the word on the left (i.e stringa) and the value is an array containing the elements on the right (ie stringx stringz).  On the right hand side, the elements are only broken by spaces, and I need to include -*$@, all of that junk.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
my %hash;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
  chomp $line;
  my ( $key, $value ) = split ' = ', $line;
  my @elems = split '\s+', $value;
  $hash{$key} = \@elems;
}
```

Your hash will be keyed by the strings on the left side of the `=`, and your values will be array references based on the right side of the `=`.

Comment: I'd make that `split /\s*=\s*/, $line, 2` if I really wanted a line to represent a key-value *pair*.

Answer (score 2):

Just so you can see that there are linear ways to do this:

```
my %hash 
    = map { $_->[0] => [ split /\s+/, $_->[1] ] } 
      map { chomp; [ split /\s*=\s*/, $_, 2 ]   } 
      <DATA>
    ;

__DATA__
Stringa = Stringx Stringz
Stringb = Stringy
Stringc = Stringw Stringx Stringu
```

Heck, while you're at it, if you add [`File::Slurp`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aSlurp), you can do this:

```
use File::Slurp qw<read_file>;
my %hash 
    = map { $_->[0] => [ split /\s+/, $_->[1] ] } 
      map { chomp; [ split /\s*=\s*/, $_, 2 ]   }
      # now you can have #-comments in your file 
      grep { !m/^\s*#/ } 
      read_file( $my_config_path )
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $hash = {};
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
  chomp($line);
  my @vals = split(/(?: = | )/, $line);
  my $key = shift(@vals);
  $hash->{$key} = \@vals;
}

for (keys %$hash) {
  print "OK: $_ => ", join(', ', @{$hash->{$_}}), "\n";
}

__END__
Stringa = Stringx Stringz
Stringb = Stringy
Stringc = Stringw Stringx Stringu
```

Comment: Why not `my($key,@vals) = split(/(?: = | )/, $line);`

Answer (score 1):

Hashes can only have scalars for values, so you can't store an array directly into a hash, but you can store a reference to an array.

```
my %hash;
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my ($key, $val) = split(/' = '/, $_);
   push @{ $hash{$key} }, split(/\s+/, $val);
}

my @abcs = @{ $hash{abc} };
my $abc = $hash{abc}[0];
```

Unlike the previously posted solutions, this accepts duplicate keys if they happen to occur.